# How to get a certain number of decimal points after the number? java

Tags: java, floating-point, numbers, decimal

i have a method printing times such as:
1.23455
1.26789
1.27853

i want it to be shortened to only two decimal places such as :
1.23
1.26
1.27

```
      System.out.println("time: "+ time);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display an output of float data with 2 decimal places in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538787/how-to-display-an-output-of-float-data-with-2-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: Here have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051395/java-float-123-129456-to-123-12-without-rounding). It answers your question thoroughly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many, many, many ways... For example you can use [String#format(String format, Object... arg)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

`System.out.println(String.format("time: %.2f", time));`

Or using `printf`, or `DecimalFormat`. I let you googlize it ;)

Comment: If this is the solution you use, you should accept his answer.

Comment: i had to wait 12 minutes chill