# Float converted into int for big values

Tags: java

I have just a basic question that why there are discrepancies between the below statements?

```
System.out.printf("%.2f \n", 55050000.41f);
System.out.printf("%.2f \n", 50.41f);
```

Output

```
55050000.00 
50.41
```

The first statement removed a decimal value and why not for 2nd statement?

Comment: The computer is a finite machine, while float are not

Comment: In other words: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: duplicate: [Decimal precision of floats](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3310276/995714), [Java float 123.129456 to 123.12 without rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5051395/995714)

Comment: @GhostCat I don't think this is about floats not storing decimal numbers exactly. It just seems to be a precision issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displayed precision of Java floating-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54869876/displayed-precision-of-java-floating-point)

Comment: seems there are many healthy conversations on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken, so can't say it really that my answer, can say once go through it.

Comment: @matt The *reason* why floats aren't storing (some) decimal numbers exactly is the same that "precision" is about, in the end.

Comment: @GhostCat I think there is a difference. Being unable to store 0.1 because it is a repeating number versus being unable to store "12345678.5" because there are too many decimal digits. Fundamentally they're both a limitation in precision though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default floating point numbers in Java are converted to 64bit double, but since you're using the f suffix the number will be interpreted as a 32bit float.

The number is so big that it doesn't fit 32bit without losing precision and 55050000 is the closest possible number.

You can play around with floats [here](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html). If you change the last bit you can see the number increases by 4.

You probably don't want to use the f suffix unless you're working with limited space.

Comment: If remove the f suffix from the values then doesn't losing the decimal values.

Comment: Without the f suffix you get higher precision, because double has much longer mantissa 52bit vs. 23bit. In this case the mantissa would look like `5.50500004099999964237213134766E7` ->  `55050000.4099999964237213134766` -> `55050000.41`