# How to round decimal part of number so it doesn't affect whole the part of number?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have this BigDecimal number - `68.65121847597993` and I want to round it like this - `68.7`, so only decimical part of number would be rounded up, but not the whole number.

I tried to use RoundingMode.HALF_UP but it rounds up the whole number as well.
Is there a way to round up only decimical part of number using java?

Comment: Do you want to actually modify the number or simply provided a rounded representation of the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to represent a number with that many decimal points, I presume you are using `BigDecimal` rather than `double`, which can only accurately represent approximately [15 significant digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542944/how-many-significant-digits-do-floats-and-doubles-have-in-java).

Starting from a [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), which you can initialize with a string, a double, or anything else you have, you can call [BigDecimal::setScale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int,%20java.math.RoundingMode)) to get the value you want.

For example:

```
import java.math.*;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String []args){
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("68.65121847597993");
    BigDecimal rounded = b.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(rounded);  // 68.65
  }
}
```

Comment: -68.65121847597993 (and its positive variant 68.65121847597993) fit nicely into a `double`.

Comment: It's on the knife's edge, getting into dangerous territory. E.g.

```
        double a = 68.65121847597993;
        double b = -68.651218475979931;
        System.out.println(a == -b);  // true
``

Comment: comparing `float` and `double` with `==` is always "on the knife's edge" ;-) but I get your point. I suppose that the OP copied that number from code that used actually a double value before, but maybe I'm wrong - so your answer is really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I would do it as in nearly every other language:

```
double input = -68.65121847597993;
double rounded = Math.floor(input * 10.0 + 0.5)/10.0;
```

With a `BigDecimal` you have more options like a rounding mode and `setScale` if you need that.

And there are third party libraries like [decimal4j](https://github.com/tools4j/decimal4j) or [Apache Commons Math](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) - though I didn't test them.

Comment: @LinFelix did you try my code? I admit that I overlooked the negative sign, so I updated my answer, but it with the negative sign it returns `-68.7`. This is due to the nature of `Math.floor()`, which does not truncate, but rounds down to the next smaller whole number, which is -687.0 if the input is -686.0121847597993 as in this example.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.###");
```

Here's a Baeldung article about it:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-round-decimal-number

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really do that because floats and doubles do not work like that.

However, this could solve your problem:

```java
round((-68.65121847597993)*10)/10f;
```

also see: [Java float 123.129456 to 123.12 without rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051395/java-float-123-129456-to-123-12-without-rounding)

Comment: Your example doesn't fully work: you are mixing `double`, `int` and `float` to a bad:
the division by `10f` makes the result `-68.69999694824219`, if the result is assigned to a `double` again. Only assigning it to a `float` yields to the correct result. Always take care of automatic casts and mixing numeric types.

Comment: Yes, it is not  a great solution I must admit

Answer (score 0):

If your value is a double, this method takes the lowest time on compiling:

```
Math.round(num * 10d) / 10d
```

Number of 0's = number of decimals

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(number));
bd = bd.setScale(decimalPlaces, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
return bd.doubleValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than change the number (so its current precision can be still used in subsequent calculations), you can control the display as follows.

```
double v = 68.65121847597993;
System.out.printf("%.1f%n", v);
```

prints

```
68.7
```